# Trying to obtain the properties of a strange region uses all memory

Tags: regions

My version of *Mathematica* is:

```
$Version
```

> `10.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (October 9, 2015)`

I produced a strange `Region` today. You can get the data here -- [click to download](http://note.youdao.com/share/?id=e89df1748e3201d9661100163de01e9b&type=note).

You can determine it is a real region:

```
region // RegionQ
```

> `True`

And you can display it with:

```
Graphics[region]
```

[image]

But if you apply `Area`, `RegionMember`, `RandomPoint` to it, *Mathematica* will run until it runs out of memory.

Is this is a bug?

This is my `.nb` file, you can download it for testing.[click to download](http://note.youdao.com/share/?id=5838a39b2f787077ac891558c0343d61&type=note)

Comment: I am wary of downloading .zip files from random locations on the Internet. Could it fit in plain text here?

Comment: @PatrickStevens. I wouldn't do it either.

Comment: The first link is to a text file, not a zip. I suspect, however, that your region is gnarly and ill defined in some parts. For instance, in the thin region this is what it looks like when zoomed in: http://i.stack.imgur.com/B5GT1.png. This will probably be *very difficult* to deal with.

Comment: @PatrickStevens Thanks for your suggestion,I'll change it soonly.

Comment: @MarcoB Yeah,the boundary is not smooth when you zoomed in,but will it relevant to this?

Comment: Link appears dead; voting to close.